# Pass an Object Array in URL Class Loader - Java

Tags: java, arrays, arguments, classloader, urlclassloader

I'm writing a java program which is pretty much modular, so very often its classes are loaded from a network share. I've found a solution for loading the classes. However it works with their arguments being int or String objects, but not a Object array a.k.a Object[]. I want it to be able to load classes which argument is only one and Object Array (in my head, it's more neat when passing more objects as argument). My edited for use with object array solution is down below, as well as the exception that throws. If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

public class LoadClassObjArrArg extends ClassLoader {

```
public LoadClassObjArrArg(String className, Object[] arg) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("file:bin/cl/");
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
        Class<?> loadedClass = ucl.loadClass(className);

        try {
            Constructor constructor = loadedClass.getConstructor(Object[].class);
            constructor.newInstance(arg);
        } catch (Exception exception) {e.printStackTrace();
            Constructor constructor = loadedClass.getConstructor();
            constructor.newInstance();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

In addition. Here is the stacktrace of the first exception in the inner try/catch block.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at LoadClassObjArrArg.<init>(LoadClassObjArrArg.java:20)
at Saba.main(Saba.java:268)
```

and the second....

```
at LoadClassObjArrArg.<init>(LoadClassObjArrArg.java:20)
at Saba.main(Saba.java:268)"
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ScreenComponentParameters.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
at LoadClassObjArrArg.<init>(LoadClassObjArrArg.java:28)
at Saba.main(Saba.java:268)
```

Comment: "in my head, it's more neat when passing more objects as argument" - tbh I'd consider this a design flaw. Why? To make it short: a) explicit parameter names and types make it easier to understand and use, b) just passing an array might hide the fact that a constructor takes way too many parameters (which hints at yet another design flaw) and c) all that casting and typechecking inside the constructor is bound to fail eventually (removing that risk is one reason why generics have been introduced).

Comment: As for the stacktrace: it's hard to map that to your code but let me try - `loadClass()` works, `getConstructor(Object[].class)` or `newInstance(arg)` fail which is why `loadedClass.getConstructor()` is called, right? And that last call doesn't find any no-argument constructor in class `ScreenComponentParameters`, is that right? Do you know why the first constructor cannot be found or fails? Why don't you log that exception too?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I pretty much agree with you, but the program has many screens and overall, classes, and many more to come. Every screen/class has different set of arguments, but some of them (args) are identical. I wont be passing soo much arguments, but for the sake of creating a template screen for newer to come, where I would know for a fact that the first value and the second for example would be the most used in all screens arguments, I've posted this question.

Comment: "fail which is why loadedClass.getConstructor() is called, right?" - Yes, the exception is thrown from Constructor constructor = loadedClass.getConstructor(); which does not find any constructor in the class. The constructor is pretty much : public ScreenComponentParameters(Object[] args) {......

Comment: Note that `getConstructor()` is looking for a _no-argument_ constructor, so if there's only `ScreenComponentParameters(Object[] args)` that method won't find it. The question is why does the inner try-catch apparently throw an exception? Your code swallows that information so that's what you need to analyze.

Comment: So there is not so obvious reason why that doesn't work? I assumed that's because of the overall method of calling the class (The URL ClassLoader).

Comment: I've updated the question with the first exception.

Comment: So as you can see the call to `newInstance(arg)` seems to be the problem. There seems to be a mismatch between the constructor and the arguments you're passing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason it works when I convert to Object array to Object when calling the new instance.

```
try {
            Constructor constructor = loadedClass.getConstructor(Object[].class);
            constructor.newInstance((Object)arg);
            
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            Constructor constructor = loadedClass.getConstructor();
            constructor.newInstance();
        }
```